# How to remove an item that is duplicating in the list

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am adding an item to the list and every time I exit the application and re-enter it duplicates the item, ie it increments the item in the list

```
 List<RespCadastro> respCadastro= new List<RespCadastro>();
        var princiapl = new PhoneDetailsGroup()
        {
            phoneNumber = respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.contactNumber,
            phoneType = respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.primaryContactType + " (principal)"
        };

respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.PhoneGroup.Add(principal);
respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.PhoneGroup.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: this isn't C, more like javascript

Comment: I think that's C#, I'm not sure though.

Comment: Please put the proper language tag, this is not C.

Comment: it´s  c# with xamarin forms

Answer (score 1):

```
var princiapl = new PhoneDetailsGroup()
                    {
                        phoneNumber = respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.contactNumber,
                        phoneType = respCadastro.result.registrationForm.contactInformation.primaryContactType + " (principal)"
                    };

var count = myList.Count(x => x.phoneNumber == principal.phoneNumber);

if (count > 0) {
  // already exists, don't add
} else {
  // add
}
```